# Emacs repeat until a given column?

Tags: emacs

When adding a divider in code I can easily repeat a '=' N times using

`C-<N> =`

where N is the number of equal signs to insert.

Is there a similarly quick command that would insert a character repeatedly up to a given column number?  So I could execute

`<magic command>-<N> =`

and get a line of equal signs from the present cursor position to column N?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't know of anything built in that can do that, but you could bind the function below to a key sequence of your choice:

```
(defun repeat-char-to-column (column character)
  "Insert copies of CHARACTER on the current line until column COLUMN.
Interactively, prompt for COLUMN and CHARACTER. If the current column is
equal to or greater than COLUMN, do nothing."
  (interactive "nRepeat to column: \ncCharacter to repeat: \n")
  (let ((cur (current-column)))
    (if (< cur column)
      (insert (make-string (- column cur) character)))))
```